# mule object using multiple times

Tags: java, rest, mule, mule-studio

i created a mule flow as:

http --> rest --> Connector1 --> Connector2 --> ResponseBack

Here in rest web service, it is accepting number of parameters, store it in object and return that object to the next component.

Connector1 receives the object and return the value(payload) to the next component(Connector2).

Now the Connector2 receives the object returned from Connector1, but it is insufficient, it also need to get the value from the object returned by rest also.
How can it be done.

Comment: Looking at your flow would be helpful in helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling the connector one or inside connector one,  save the  object returned by rest as a flow (invocation) variable.

This way when you reach connector two, you can have both response from connector one and
the  object returned by rest.

```
  <set-variable value="#[payload]" variableName="objFromRest"></set-variable>
```

or

```
  msg.setInvocationProperty(key, value);
```

and to retrieve them

```
  msg.getInvocationProperty(key);

or   #[flowVars['key']]
```

Refer to the following link for more information of using the Mule Expression Language and using Flow Variables.

[Mule Expression Language](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL)

Comment: can u give me any reference link which used the above method, so it would be helpful.